# Make a subsection remove part of the parent section

Tags: sectioning, formatting

I'm working from a format that has been specified for me (there are certain requirements I must follow). I haven't been able to figure out how to get my section headings to look like this:

(level 1)     Part 1

(level 2)     1.1

(level 3)     1.1.1

etc.

I'm currently using the following code to modify the level 1 section header:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{Part \arabic{section}}
```

However, when I use `\subsection`, it shows Part 2.1 when it needs to be just 2.1. All my `\section` headings needs to have "Part" in them, while all other subheadings should just have the section numbers.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `\usepackage{chngcntr} \counterwithin*{subsection}{section}` should do the trick, at least for level 2. What would you like to have for level 3: `1` or `1.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\thesubsection` uses `\thesection` by default (class `article` and some other classes). Thus `\thesubsection` needs to be changed to use `\arabic{section}` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{Part \arabic{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Perfect, thank you! That seems so obvious now.